# Invoking full screen without user interaction

Tags: javascript, html

Is it possible to have a web page enter full screen without user interaction like this?

```html
<body onload="openFullscreen()"></body>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This will be very annoying for your site visitors. Especially those visitors who have a slow internet connection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is not possible.

I ran the following snippet in my browser console:

```
var e = document.getElementById('answers');
(e.webkitRequestFullScreen || e.mozRequestFullScreen).apply(e);
```

Chrome told me:

Failed to execute 'requestFullScreen' on 'Element': API can only be initiated by a user gesture.

Firefox told me:

Request for full-screen was denied because Element.mozRequestFullScreen() was not called from inside a short running user-generated event handler.

That is a restriction put in place to prevent abuse, similar to that on `window.open` (see this or this question for example).

You might be able to achieve this, but this will vary based upon your operating system.

This might work:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('html').click(function () {
        if (screenfull.isFullscreen !== true) {
            screenfull.toggle();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: If my answer helped you, please mark the green checkmark and upvote!.

Answer (score 1):

It can be allowed by changing a browser setting and using the [Fullscreen API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fullscreen_API). The setting is for Firefox only - couldn't find a solution for Chrome.

**Firefox**

1. Go to about:config
2. Set this value to *false*: `full-screen-api.allow-trusted-requests-only`

This is useful if you always need full screen mode on, when accessing your web site from a device under your control.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your use case, you might be able to use **Chrome Kiosk mode** which runs in full screen.  Obviously this won't work from normal browser access to a web site, but works well for running interactive browser/web pages, etc., locally in full screen.

e.g. I have this in a (windows) batch file for running kiosk mode in Chrome:

```
"c:\Program files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --kiosk "127.0.0.1/client" --user-data-dir="c:\chrome_dir"
```

You would replace 127.0.0.1/client with your url.

*Note: user_data_dir allows separate history/preferences, etc., from your 'normal' chrome usage - you might not need this.*